# (iphone) what happens to subviews when superview is dealloced?

Tags: iphone, view, subview, retain

Suppose a view(A) has subviews.
The view(A) is getting dealloced because its retain count goes zero.

What happens to the subviews of view(A)?
Do they get detached(removed from view A) and their retain count decrease accordingly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by 'view' you actually mean 'instance of UIView':

Views retain their subviews, and therefor, if a view gets deallocated, it's subviews get released and their retain count decreases by one.

I'm not sure, but I *guess* the view hierarchy is implemented like this:

```
@interface UIView : UIResponder {
  NSArray *_subviews;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *subviews;

@end

@implementation UIView
@synthesize subviews;
- (void)dealloc {
  [subviews release];
  [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

---

You can **roughly** say that NSObject declares an unsigned integer which is the retain count, like this:

```
unsigned retainCount;
```

Then, these would be the implementations of `-[id<NSObject> retain]` and `-[id<NSObject> release]`:

```
- (void)retain {
  retainCount++;
}

- (void)release {
  retainCount--;
  if (retainCount == 0) {
    [self dealloc];
  }
}
```

Comment: do you mean subview's retain count decreases by one and it gets released if retain count reaches zero?

Comment: It gets deallocated when the retain count reaches zero. Retain increases the retain count, release decreases the retain count. Whenever the retain count reaches zero it will be deallocated and you cannot use it anymore.

Comment: It's not quite like you wrote... when a view get removed it will call [view removeFromSuperview] in all of it's subviews .. so they will remove themself from their parent. If there are not other retains on this view dealloc will get called. Sometimes it is handy to overwrite this function to clean up stuff that would prevent the call of dealloc because of retains like timers or stuff like that.

Comment: @Bastian, when you say "when a view get removed it will call [view removeFromSuperview] in all of it's subviews", you mean "when a view gets dealloced it will call..." ?

Comment: yes... when a view gets deallocated it will call it in all subviews

Comment: so radek's pseudo code should be [subviews removeFromSuperview] rather than [subviews release]

Answer (score 0):

All subviews will be released.

Answer (score 0):

If the main view is released or deallocated then all the child view inside it will also be deallocated

Answer (score 0):

The superview's dealloc will call into subviews' **removedFromSuperview**, then into subviews' **willMoveToSuperview** to "Tells the view that its superview is about to change to the specified superview.", in this case about to be dealloced.

Setting a debug point in subview's **willMoveToSuperview** can verify this easily.

So if subviews kvo superview's property, here is good place to removeObserver because if we do it subviews dealloc, which will be called later, it is already too late. We will get be exception like, 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x135a9a600 of class UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.